# Randomized Alogrithms

Tags: algorithms

A hash function $h : [m] \to [n]$ is often used to store elements of $[m]$ in a table of
size $n$. Typically $n \ll m$, and there is a potential scope of collision. A utility
of pairwise-independent families is that for every “small” set $S \subseteq [m]$, a randomly
picked hash function is collision-free with reasonable probability.
Let $H$ be a pairwise-independent family of hash functions. Let $S \subseteq [m]$ be such that
|S| 6
√
n
10 . Show that the probability that a uniformly randomly sampled function
$h$ from $H$ is injective on $S$ (i.e., $h(a) \neq h(b)$ whenever $a, b \in S$ and $a \neq b$) with
probability at least $199/200$.

Comment: Welcome to MSE! I've edited your question to use mathjax, though I can't figure out what you mean by |S| 6 $\sqrt{}$ n 10. Would you mind clarifying so I can finish the edit?

Comment: Also, what have you tried? Do you have any ideas of your own? Once we have a better idea of exactly where you're struggling, we can help you better ^_^